jQuery auto complete on Modal
A Bootstrap Modal is open when I click on #add. I would like to show autocomplete on a input box in Modal. My code is like below.
$("#add").on("click", function () {
  var selector = $("#addModal");
  selector.find(".is-invalid").removeClass("is-invalid");
  selector.find(".error-message").remove();
  selector.modal("show");
  selector.find("form").trigger("reset");

  $("#addModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
    if (!$("#invoice_name").data("ui-autocomplete")) {
      var validOptions = ["Bold", "Normal", "Default", "Banana", "Mango"];
      var previousValue = "";

      $("#invoice_name")
        .autocomplete({
          autoFocus: true,
          source: validOptions,
        })
        .keyup(function () {
          var isValid = false;
          for (var i in validOptions) {
            if (validOptions[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
              isValid = true;
            }
          }
          if (!isValid) {
            this.value = previousValue;
          } else {
            previousValue = this.value;
          }
        });
    }
  });
});

But the autocomplete is not working. I am not getting any error in browser console.

What does "not working" mean? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Thanks @NicoHaase. Actually autocomplete is not appearing in the input box. I made an alert. It was working. I am not getting any clue to solve the issue.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What do you mean by "I made an alert"? Maybe if (!$('#invoice_name').data('ui-autocomplete')) { is not matching?

Thinking you might need to initialize Autocomplete before you show the Modal. Also you are initializing it each time the Modal is Shown. If the options are not changing, maybe you need to just initialize it once.

Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Add:
   $( "#invoice_name" ).autocomplete( "option", "appendTo", ".modal-body" );

By default, the autocomplete dropdown is appended to the body of the document. This could lead to positioning issues, especially within a modal, where the dropdown may not align correctly or be hidden behind other elements.
By specifying the appendTo option as ".modal-body", the autocomplete suggestions are appended directly inside the modal's body.
Remove:
The keyup function you provided is unnecessary if you're already using the jQuery UI autocomplete widget, which handles filtering and suggestions for you.Thats why i removed that part


$('#add').on('click', function () {
        var selector = $('#addModal');
        selector.find('.is-invalid').removeClass('is-invalid');
        selector.find('.error-message').remove();
        selector.modal('show')
        selector.find('form').trigger('reset');

        $('#addModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            if (!$('#invoice_name').data('ui-autocomplete')) {
                var validOptions = ["Bold", "Normal", "Default", "Banana", "Mango"];
        
                $('#invoice_name').autocomplete({
                    autoFocus: true,
                    source: validOptions
                });
        $( "#invoice_name" ).autocomplete( "option", "appendTo", ".modal-body" );
            }
        });
 });



